# copy-paste bleed over in privileges description on S-O

Tags: bug

https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-community-wiki has this at the bottom, despite being about the "Edit Community Wiki" privilege.

> Self answer questions
>
> Typically, a new user with privilege level less than this will have to
>   wait for 8 hours after posting their question to put in an answer of
>   their own.
>
> Achieving this privilege level allows the user to post answers on
>   their own questions, without having to wait for 8 hours.

Answer (score 1):

That's status by design.

It's saying that when you have achieved the ability to edit community wiki questions you will also be granted the ability to answer your own questions without waiting the 8 hours that would be required of you, if you didn't have this privilege.

So user without this privilege:

Asks question -> 8 hours later can answer own question.

User with this privilege:

Asks question -> instantly can answer own question

Comment: oh. okay. the wording seems confusing to me. if it basically does two things, i'd think we'd want to lead off the whole page with something like "Achieving this privilege level allows you to: 1) edit community wiki posts, 2) instantly answer your own questions" and then go on to the Q&A about the community wiki. really, it seems like the instant-self-answer should be a totally separate permission.